# bbpress query topics with specific reply meta

Tags: bbpress

I want to get topics using wp_query but filter only the topics results that have replies with a specific meta.

To better understand I have a "Mark as a solution" functionality implemented for each reply and I want to search only the topics that have the _bbp_is_solution meta added to a reply.

Below I can get only the replies but I want to search in the topic title and content:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'reply',
    'meta_key' => '_bbp_solution',
    'meta_value' => 1,
    'posts_per_page' => -1
);
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

Please let me know if you know any solution

All the best

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up adding a meta to the topic and then using that in the query. Seems a simpler solution

Take care